# How to get the aggregate of all the confusion matrix in python when Stratified 10 fold cross validation is applied

Tags: python, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray, confusion-matrix

I am using 10-fold cross-validation and evaluating the model on the basis of accuracy and precision.

The confusion matrix is generated 10 times for each model. How can I aggregate the confusion matrix and calculate the accuracy?

Comment: Can you give a sample of what is your input and what you would like see in output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross_val_predict` function as follows and use it result as `confusion_matrix()` argument.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=5)
cm = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
```